# Is AWS Amplify insecure?

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've been given the task of implementing a user *Sign In / Sign Up* flow in a react native app. There is nothing too fancy about this app in particular. The usual Sign In, Sign Up (with SMS Verification) and Password Reset screens suffice. So I went looking for identity providers. Auth0 and AWS Cognito were the most suitable finds. Auth0 was considered too expensive by my managers so we discarded it. Which left me with the Cognito option.

According to the [docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#composing-your-own-authenticator), it is possible to completely replace the default UI (which is something that pleases the UI/UX team) but still using the underlying infrastructure. One thing that concerns our team very much is security. According to [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) and [this](https://auth0.com/docs/design/browser-based-vs-native-experience-on-mobile#phishing-and-security-issues), authorization requests should only be made through external agents (mobile user browsers). So I went digging into the aws-amplify's source code and found that ultimately what it [does](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/f37cff7a099b9f2463239b971e6bbefef7d204c9/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/src/Client.js#L22) (and correct me if I'm wrong here,  please) is just a simple API request to the AWS auth endpoints passing my ClientId and other attributes.

This got me a little worried about the security of the interactions with AWS. As AWS endpoints are secure, I know a mitm attack is discarded.

*But what keeps an attacker of decompiling my mobile app, getting access to the ClientId and making direct requests to AWS? Is AWS Amplify's really that insecure or am I missing something here?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many attacks that are possible but at a high level 3 stand out
Credential compromise
Social engineering
DoS

Credential compromise
Your account credentials should not be exposed, STS credentials are time limited and need you to specifically grant permissions to the pool to access aws services
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html
you need to give a least privilege, follow approach outlined here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege

Social engineering attack
I guess exposed ClientId from a decompiled source could be used but would need to be combined with other user data so as a general rule lock down everything that links to your account that could be combined with the Client Id in a social attack

Dos
AWS provides what it calls "Advanced Security" in pools
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-advanced-security.html

this should be required when building Cognito Apps its comprehensive

Security threats constantly evolve, AWS do a good job, there are security advantages in using
Cloudfront
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/security.html

CloudTrail
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/